# Wondering why my code is outputing an assertion error as my previous codes work on jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, assertion

#code picture is below and it keeps giving me an error output, assertion error when I did an assert line above

[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqhgi.png):

Comment: The error seems clear: `atom1` is not in the `myCarbons` list. Use `print(myCarbons)` to see what's in the list.

Comment: In order to help you you should add an example of the `df`, the `distNames[0]`